# jQuery click event also fires a submit form button click event

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two different jQuery click actions. One is to launch a modal 'feedback' window, the other is to perform some validation, disable and grey out the form button and finally submit a form.

Both work just fine independently.

The code for the model window is in the main template page as it is used throughout the website. The code that handles the submit event is within the contact page only.

The trouble I am having is that the 'launch model' action also seems to trigger the form submit event... However clicking the form submit button does not launch the modal window.

Obviously I'd like the modal window to launch without trying to submit the form.

### Launch modal code

```
jQuery(function ($) {            
        // Load dialog on click
        $('.feedbackModal').click(function (e) {
            $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

### Form submit event code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(':submit').click(function (e) {            
        var clicked = $(this);
        // form validation stuff here 
        $(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(clicked).css({
            "font-size": "14px",
            "background": "#999999"
        });
        $(clicked).val("Submitting...");
        $("#paymentform").submit();
    });
});
```

Any ideas why launching my modal window also submits my form?

Many thanks.

Comment: Post your HTML... the button is probably causing a postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(':submit')` selects any input / button element.

Try using a more specific selector, e.g. `$('#paymentSubmit')`